# Is there a plugin for Atom to ignore searching in comments?

Tags: javascript, search, find, comments, atom-editor

I have a large corpus of ES6 code. A search returns all occurences of a string or regular expression, but I'd like an option that will either show or hide hits within comments. Atom can already parse the language enough to discern code vs comments, so it shouldn't be much of a stretch to make search results sensitive to code, comments or both.

Does anyone know if a plugin to enable this behavior already exists? I can't seem to find it if it does, and if I get the urge to write it, I don't want to just be spinning wheels.